# Dimension of Fibres

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space

I want to check the dimensions of fibres of projections of $V=Z(y_0(x_0^2-x_1^2)+y_1x_1x_2) \subseteq \mathbb{P}^2 \times \mathbb{P}^1$, $p : V \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^2, q : V \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$. Is it true that dimension of all fibres of $q$ is $1$ since it is given by one polynomial equation (a hypersurface of $\mathbb{P}^2$)? What about dimension of fibres of $p$? My guess for $p$ the dimension is $0$ except for $[0:0:1]$. Thank you.

Comment: For $ q $, you're right. For $ p $, there are more points over which the dimension is $ 1 $. For instance, $ [1:1:0] $.

Comment: @CraniumClamp thank you, I missed that possibility. I think those are the only points for dimension 1, is it correct? Because if $x_0=x_1 \neq 0$ and $x_2 \neq 0$, $y_1$ must be $0$

Comment: Eh, no, there's more. How about $ [1:-1:0] $. I guess you're missing the point here. You need to look for solutions to $ x_0^2 - x_1^2 = x_1x_2 = 0 $.

Comment: @CraniumClamp ah yes, I didn't look clearly the equations, thanks